# Only show contextMenu when user is right clicking an item

Tags: javafx, treeview

I have the following cellValueFactory on treeView to add contextMenu and dragAndDrop functionality:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<String>, TreeCell<String>>() {
        @Override

        public TreeCell<String> call(TreeView<String> stringTreeView) {
            TreeCell<String> treeCell = new TreeCell<String>() {
                @Override

                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (!empty && item != null) {
                        setText(item);
                        setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());

                        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Delete");
                        item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                                System.out.println("Here I will add some delete functionality");
                            }
                        });
                        contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item2);

                        treeView.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

                        setContextMenu(contextMenu);

                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(null);

                    }
                }
            };

            addDragAndDrop(treeCell);
            treeView.setEditable(true);
            return treeCell;
        }

    });
```

The drag and drop works great, and the contextMenu shows up, but it shows up on everything I right click on inside the treeview. How can I make it only appear when the user is actually right clicking an item in  the treeview?

Comment: Add the context menu to the cell instead of the Tree.

Comment: You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks again @james_D :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the context menu on both the `TreeView` and the `TreeCell`. Just set it on the `TreeCell`. Also, you should remove it in the case that the cell is empty:

```
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty && item != null) {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());

                    final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

                    MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("Delete");
                    item2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("Here I will add some delete functionality");
                        }
                    });
                    contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item2);

                    // remove this line:
                    //treeView.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

                    setContextMenu(contextMenu);

                } else {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);

                    setContextMenu(null);
                }
            }
```